# Get wordpress parent template name

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the pages parent template name.  I know I can use get_page_template() for the current page, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the parents one.

Is it also possible to get just the templates name instead of the path to it?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, get_page_template() can only return the file path of the current page. Use get_page_template_slug() instead, which returns just the file-name and can accept a post ID as an argument. You can combine it with wp_get_post_parent_id() to get the parent page's ID.

```
get_page_template_slug(wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_id()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this for get parent page template name
/********** GET PAGES BY PARAMS ************/

/*-- Get root parent of a page --*/
function get_root_page($page_id) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $parent = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='page' AND ID = '$page_id'");

    if ($parent == 0) 
        return $page_id;
    else 
        return get_root_page($parent);
}

/*-- Get page name by ID --*/
function get_page_name_by_ID($page_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $page_name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '$page_id'");
    return $page_name;
}

/*-- Get page ID by Page Template --*/
function get_page_ID_by_page_template($template_name)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $page_ID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value = '$template_name' AND meta_key = '_wp_page_template'");
    return $page_ID;
}

/* -- Get page ID by Custom Field Value -- */
function get_page_ID_by_custom_field_value($custom_field, $value)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $page_ID = $wpdb->get_var(" 
        SELECT wposts.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
        WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
        AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '$custom_field' 
        AND (wpostmeta.meta_value like '$value,%' OR wpostmeta.meta_value like '%,$value,%' OR wpostmeta.meta_value like '%,$value' OR wpostmeta.meta_value = '$value')        
        AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND wposts.post_type = 'page'
        LIMIT 0, 1");

    return $page_ID;
}
```