# How to get page template name? e.g. Template Name: template name

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to get the name of the page template?
 I mean in a page template, at the beginning we write `Template Name: template name`
I want "`template name`" by page-id

I've tried `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true) and get_page_template_slug($post_id)` but none of the function helped

Comment: Is the answer right there in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862290/get-wordpress-parent-template-name? No, never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
As I'm going to use inside WordPress admin 
I've used regular expression.
It's something like this `preg_match('/\bTemplate Name: [a-zA-Z0-9\s\-_]+\b/',$file,$template);`.
`$file` is the file name from `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true)`

It gives me `Template Name: template name` and then I used some array functions to get an actual part from returned array from `preg_match`.

I hope this solution will help other developers in future.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bit more proper way to do that.
Saying we have already template path:

```
$template_path = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true);
```

Then we just do this:

```
$templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
echo $templates[$template_path];
```

it outputs template name.
as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to function.php

```
add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');
function show_template() {
   global $template;
   echo basename($template);
}
```

Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts :). I've tried your code and it's printing the filename only.
e.g. 'template-name.php'. I want `template name` from  `Template Name: template name` by post-id